# If $\mu$ is a (sub-)probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mu(\left\{x\right\})=0$ for all continuity points $x$ of the DF of $\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mu$ be a (sub-)probability measure on $\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right)$ and $F$ be the distribution function of $\mu$. How can we deduce $$\mu\left(\left\{x\right\}\right)=0\;\;\;\text{for all continuity points }x\in\mathbb{R}\text{ of }F\tag{1}$$ from the definition of $\mu$?

---

I've tried the following:

- Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\nu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ be a family of pairwise disjoint
  sets with positive $\nu$-measure
- We can show, that $\mathcal{F}$ is at most countable

Thus, since $$\mathcal{F}=\left\{\left\{x\right\}:x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, it's impossible that $$\mu\left(\left\{x\right\}\right)>0\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R}$$ How can we conclude that $(1)$ must be true?

Comment: How about $\mu(A) := \chi_A(0)$? That's a probability measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ with $\mu(\{0\}) = 1$ (i.e. the only possible outcome is $0$).

Comment: @AlexR You're absolutely right. I've made an additional assumption. Now, the statement should be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $$F(x) := \mu(-\infty,x].$$
1. Let $(x_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an arbitrary sequence such that $x_j \uparrow x$. Conclude from the continuity of the measure that $$F(x-) = \lim_{j \to \infty} F(x_j) = \mu((-\infty,x)).$$
2. Let $(x_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_j \downarrow x$. Show that $$F(x) = \lim_{j \to \infty} F(x_j) = \mu((-\infty,x]).$$
3. Conclude that for any continuity point $x$ of $F$, we have $$\mu(\{x\})=0.$$